# Call a feathers hook from another hook

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-hook

Is there any way to create a hook that calls 2 different other hooks and then do a `||` between them?

I would like to call the `authenticate('jwt')` hook and if this one fails call a custom hook to see if the request is local (so I don't need authentication). If the second hook is positive, I'll go on with the request. If both fail, then it's a no go.

If I call the hooks one after another the first fails and so the service fails.

Can this be achieved or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using feathers-hooks-common you can do an `iff` chain, e.g.

```
const { iff, isProvider } = require('feathers-hooks-common');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: iff(isProvider('external'), authenticate('jwt')
  }
}
```

Comment: For reference, I also found this: https://hooks-common.feathersjs.com/overview.html